# install latest psutil version in centos 6.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, versioning, psutil

My system os version is **(centos)6.7** with installed python version is **2.6.***
When I tried to install a python module **psutil**
 with a command

```
yum install python-psutil
```

But the installed version is **0.3.6** something...

But the latest version of psutil module is **3.2.2**

What might be the problem? How to solve it ? Do I need to update python version ?

or

Update psutil version ? If so how to install particular version of psutil ?

This might not be a great question to ask, But Please give some suggestion what to do or Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: When you use yum to install the **python-psutil** package, it will be installed from the centos repository. You should install it via pip: `pip install psutil`

Comment: For that I need to install pip. But While installing pip I am getting warning message like : Your System SSL Connection prevented kind of. Is that a problem ?

Comment: I don't know but it seems like a network related issue.

Answer (score 9):

**Python2**

```
yum install gcc python-devel
pip install psutil
```

**Python3**

```
yum install gcc python3-devel
pip3 install psutil
```